# Could not start Jmeter properly

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, jmeter

I am trying to run **jmeter**  on linux machine. Its throwing this warning and **jmeter** is 
not working properly.

```
[warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: No JAVA_CMD set for run_java, falling back to JAVA_CMD = java
java.lang.Throwable: Could not access /usr/share/jmeter/lib/junit
at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:97)
```

I have already installed **JUNIT** and **JDBC.MYSQL Connector**.

Also, When i am setting **TEST USERS** , it is not showing JDBC Configuration window.

I want to know what i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may have to create a symbolic link from `/usr/share/jmeter/lib/junit` to your installation of junit.

Comment: your suggestion is appreciated ,but can you tell me how to create that symbolic link.

Comment: In my case on Ubuntu is was `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/junit /usr/share/jmeter/lib/junit`